# Modify scaffold :string for :text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, scaffolding

I have a scaffold, but it fails because the text of the users is longer than string permits. So I would like to change the kind of data, `rails g scaffold Dreams Dream:string` for `Dreams:text`, 
It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already migrate, undo it:

```
rake db:rollback
rails destroy scaffold Dreams Dream:string
```

And redo it

```
rails generate scaffold Dreams Dream:text
rake db:migrate
```

You don't need to make `rake db:rollback` and `rake db:migrate` if you have just generated your scaffold.

If it is not your last migration, you can undo it with:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<version>
# version is the number of your migration file you want to revert
```

---

You can create a new migration:

```
rails generate migration change_dream_type_in_dreams
```

and open migration to use `change_column`

```
def self.up
  change_column :dreams, :dream, :text
end

def self.down
  change_column :dreams, :dream, :string
end
```

Finally, `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: I have it already migrated, and i have all a project on this scaffold, its impossible destroy it now. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I put a second solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the scaffold should be a singular noun like `User` and in your case, it should be `Dream`, Rails will not allow `Dreams` unless you pass `--force-plural` option.

Second, the column name should also be singular, though it can be plural, but rails convention in general is to have singular column names.

And yes, you are right!

```
rails g scaffold Dream dream:text
```

`text` is the option you are looking for. And if you do not specify anything with `dream`, Rails will take it as `string`.

Comment: If you think, this is the valid answer, and helped you, you can accept it.

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: Great! As a suggestion i recomend put a text that say acept answer.

Comment: @user2284348 Please go to http://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a quick overview of how actually stackoverflow works. Happy coding.